# Counting recent visits based on date range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one column with Name.
I have a 2nd column with Date associated with a visit.
I wanted to generate a count of how many times the person has visited in a previous number of days. 
If the number is greater than X, I want to fill another column with match.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to filter out names that don't match the row, while simultaneously counting how many times that person has dates that fall within the 7 day range.

So if John visited on 1/23, 2/4, 2/6, and 2/8, and the range is 7 days, it should add "3" to the "recent visits" column next to John's 2/8 row, fill 2 into the "recent visits" column for 2/6, and 1 for 2/4 and 1/23.

There will be other rows with other names that will have the same requirements, so it would also need to filter out names that don't match John.

What I'm trying to do with this, is trigger an alert through Zapier to send an email when there is a frequent visitor match.

Answer (score 1):

**cell C2:** `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""))`

**cell D2:**

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA($A$2:$B), 
 "select A where B >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
             and B <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
             and A = '"&C3&"'", 0))
```

and drag down from **D2** cell

[image]